# Is there a required ceiling height for a garage door opener?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I recently bought a bank-owned house.  They converted the garage into a living space and I would like to take it back to being a garage.  I was hoping to install a garage door opener for the new door, and I was wondering how tall do the ceilings need to be in the garage in order for a garage door opener?

Currently, the ceiling is 7' 9" with the plaster on it, but I will be gutting the entire thing to redo the electrical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most garage door openers need just a few inches above the garage door to work. If you have 6 inches above the opened garage door you should be fine.

Some garage door openers need more space above the motor than others. Chain drives with the chain sprocket on top come to mind.